# How to split a string starting at the beginning of a regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have some data in a string, for example

```
const rawData = `1   Jon Doe 3434 535 3 3 353 HI 3535
2    Jane Smith 23 5235 5 5 2352 HELLO 3543
3      Some Guy 4534 35 5345 4 5345 MEOW 4354`
```

I want to use the .split() method to make each line (starting with the order number to the end of the last value) its own value in an array.

I have tried

```
rawData.split(/([0-9]+\s+[A-Z][a-z])/g);
```

the regex finds a number followed by some whitespace then a capital letter and a lower cased letter (the order number until the start of the first name)

this returns

```
["", "1 Jo", "n Doe 3434 535 3 3 353 HI 3535", "2 Ja", "ne Smith 23 5235 5 5 2352 HELLO 3543", "3 So", "me Guy 4534 35 5345 4 5345 MEOW 4354"]
```

I would like to have 3 values by splitting the string at the start of the regex. So I would like to end up with:

```
["1 Jon Doe 3434 535 3 3 353 HI 3535", "2 Jane Smith 23 5235 5 5 2352 HELLO 3543", "3 Some Guy 4534 35 5345 4 5345 MEOW 4354"]
```

I can think a workaround, using a for loop to join the values in the array after. I'm curious if there is a way to do it on one line. Thanks!

EDIT

I just found out about lookahead in regex, this works:

```
rawData.split(/\s(?=\d+\s+[A-Z][a-z])/g);
```

Comment: I think you mean "at the start of a string returned by a regex", not at the start of the regex itself.

Comment: @isherwood yup thats what I mean, still new to using regex so thanks for clarifying

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj that worked, thanks! although I found a way to do it if they weren't on new lines, added to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not split by new line?

```js
const rawData = `1   Jon Doe 3434 535 3 3 353 HI 3535
2    Jane Smith 23 5235 5 5 2352 HELLO 3543
3      Some Guy 4534 35 5345 4 5345 MEOW 4354`,
    result = rawData.split(/\n/);

console.log(result);
```